# Model not showing up in cycles view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view

In Rendered view my model shows up but it won't start rendering the textures. Video provided for a better example.
https://youtu.be/Apmt2vcUigU

Comment: if you have an AMD graphic card there's a problem with the latest drivers, so try a previous one or try to enable Render panel > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.